# Tab Page launching a timer

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer

I have a project that uses a System.Timers.Timer to update the position of motors.  I am adding 3 more motors and would like to control each of them the same way as the first.   I tried moving my controls to a Tab Control but my update timers are not triggering.  I made the

`UpdateTimer.SynchronizingObject = TheMainForm;`

Because if I tried to make it the Tab Page I got an error.  I am very new to threaded projects. What am I doing wrong.  Will post more code if its needed.

Comment: Better show everything related to creating, configuring and starting of the timers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to keep the timer on the main form then call each update method from that main timer.